# Add expandible Node inside another node

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView Node who have nodes inside it I.E

[image]

So I want to add another Node inside "BD 1" (expansive one). So that node is in my parent. I try to add as:

```
parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes.Add(changeOrderDesignItemName);
```

But it's added as one more item of "BD 1" Node

[image]

How can I add it as expandibleitem inside this node instead be part of all node?

Comment: The first picture and the second one are completely different, so it's not clear at all what you mean.

Comment: Sorry fix it. In first picture I didn't add node yet, for default  "BD 1" Node have first 4 nodes inside it. Then when I create new node (CO 1), it's created but is not expandible as "BD 1" @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: `parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes`  This is a really hard way to manage the tree.  Just find the parent node you want to work with and its node collection.  I'm still confused what the issue is.

Comment: @LarsTech The issue seems to be that "CO1" is a node while the OP wants it to be an "expandible node"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Or does he mean CO1 should be part of the Design node that's barely visible at the top?

Comment: my parent node is `parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes`, I want to add to this node another node but as expandible one, like "BD 1" @LarsTech

Comment: Any node that has children nodes becomes expandable.

Comment: And why this one no have expandible [+]? @LarsTech

Comment: It has no child nodes.

Comment: Got it!, but now how can I get the index of the node I just create I.E. When I create this node:  `parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes.Add(changeOrderDesignItemName);`, how can I get that node if it's in the same node of the other four items? @LarsTech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you are making this hard to manage your TreeView nodes when relying on index positions like this:

```
parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes
```

To get the reference of the node you just added, `nodes.Add(...)` is actually a function that returns the new node.  So you can write it like this:

```
TreeNode tn = parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[iDesign].Nodes.Add(changeOrderDesignItemName);
```

Now `tn` is the new node you just added, and you can simple add more child nodes to it like this:

```
tn.Nodes.Add("Child node");
```